# What does 冒了出来 mean here?

Tags: meaning

通过网络写作，很多年轻的写手冒了出来，然后重新回归到传统的出版方式出书，这是好事。

Many young writers emerge on the internet and later turn to more traditional forms of book publishing, which is a good thing.

I think 冒了出来 means 'emerge', but later it says '重新回归到传统的出版方式‘ If they emerged on the internet, they can't return to traditional book publishing, because they were never there.

If 冒出来 is 'emerge', I'd have to set 回归 not as 'return， regress' but 'turn to'， so maybe there is some other meaning for '冒出来‘ here？？

Comment: You're right about `冒出来` and `回归`. It is just some logical error in original Chinese sentence.

Comment: @Pedroski
I think one can return to sth. one has not experienced oneself, if the reference point is not oneself but an (not necessarily mentioned) other part. So, “the young writers returned to more traditional ways of publishing” is not per se erroneous.
Or, which word would you use, instead of return, to express that they are now publishing in paper, which is more traditional, whereas they had been using but the Internet before?

Comment: I would use 'turn to', as I did above. Chinese logic and Western logic diverge, so I would not be in the least surprised if it seems logical in Chinese to ‘return‘ to a place you have never been. I was more concerned about the meaning of 冒出来。

Comment: @Pedroski You can't physically return to a place you've never been. But 回归 here is figurative 'regress in trend' instead of physical 'return'. So I guess it's not much of a divergence in logic or culture, rather a different way of expression.

Answer (score 1):

1 冒出来 literally means to pop up, to suddenly appear. In this context, it means to become popular. For example：最近几年冒出来了很多互联网公司，他们的增长速度让人吃惊。

2 回归  here it  means come back to former situation. For example: 他们的心情最终会回归平静的。

Answer (score 1):

What the author really means 回归 is 网络写作 的(出版方式) 回归 传统的(出版方式)

```
                     to be known by broad public                              
                    /                   ^
                   / （“回归”）          | (冒了出来)
                  \/                    |
Traditional writting --------->  Internet writting
 (传统的出版方式)   <------ 回归 -------- (网络写作 (的出版方式)）
```

Answer (score 0):

here 冒出来 means **to be known by broad public**. the way they made them popular is by posting blogs on the web, which is considered to be a trendy way of publish. Howerver, some publisher may think it's better to compile all their blogs into one book, and if the authors of the blog agrees, then the auter is to be said RETURN to the traditional means of publish.

One xample, during a marathron, a runner emerged from the bush and joined the group in the halfway. after he was caught by the referee, he was aksed to return to the starting point.

Comment: Well, yeah, emerge only makes sense in the context of 'emerge into the public domain, become known to the general (reading) public'. So it is a figurative use of 'emerge', not a literal one. If the guy was not at the starting point, he cannot return there, not in my logic, but I see that the Chinese. regard that differently. If you have never visited 北京, can you '回归到北京‘?

Answer (score 0):

we usually use 回归 in two ways.

1. you tried to finish a task in different ways, but you failed, eventually you have to go backwards to the traditional way to do it. （你最终回归到传统的方式去完成某事。）
2. HongKong's return to China.（香港回归到中国。）

BTW, you cannot 回归北京, you can say 我明天回北京， but you cannot say 我明天回归北京。

Answer (score 0):

It is the general trend that has returned to the traditional, paperback way, because the trend once was like that.

The young new writers are those who are driving this trend.

There's no logic mistake.